# Position a box out of the main DIV but still relate to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I came across a blockage and I can't seem to be able to move on. I'm trying to move a little box with a few options (such as report, like, dislike etc.) out of the main DIV, but still keep it **glued to it from the outside**. Let me demonstrate with an image:

[image: Demonstration]

I have tried achieving this a few ways, but the problem is that the box is in the center of the body, meaning there's some padding from the left and the right (responsive padding set via Bootstrap's classes) so I'm quite unable to calculate the whole thing.

I have tried like this via jQuery:

```
$('.image-options').css('right', $('.image-options').parent().width() + 50 + 'px');

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.image-options').css('right', $('.image-options').parent().width() + 50 + 'px');
})
```

Where `.image-options` is the *option box* and its parent is `Main DIV`. I imagined the option box to have a width of **50px** all the time, so I assume this makes it a bit easier for the whole positioning issue.

I'm building my website on top of **Bootstrap 3**, so I'm using quite a lot of their classes. This is how my HTML looks like (Ignore the templating syntax):

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        {% include "overall_header.twig" %}

        <div class="row">
            <section class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="upload-space">
                    <!-- This is the options box -->
                    <div class="affix image-options">
                        Report
                    </div>      

                    <div class="row inner">
                        <section class="col-lg-12">

                            <section class="row">

                                <div class="col-lg-12 center">
                                    <a href="{{ S_IMAGE_URL }}" class="lightview">
                                        <img src="{{ S_IMAGE_URL }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{ S_IMAGE_NAME }}" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="direct_url">Direct:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select()" value="{{ S_IMAGE_URL }}" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="direct_url">Thumbnail:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select()" value="{{ S_IMAGE_THUMB }}" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="direct_url">Direct:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select()" value="{{ S_IMAGE_BBCODE }}" readonly>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="direct_url">Direct:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" onclick="this.select()" value="{{ S_IMAGE_HTML }}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- col -->

                            </section> <!-- row -->
                        </section> <!-- col -->
                    </div><!-- .row.inner -->
                </div>
            </section>
        </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- Main column -->
</div><!-- Content -->
{% endblock content %}
```

And this is the little CSS I wrote for my options box:

```
.image-options {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

`.upload-space` is *Main DIV* in our case.

---

**How do I make the options box stay glued to the Main DIV all the time even though the page is responsive and the Main DIV's width/height might differ based on the browser size?**

Thanks.

Comment: Negative margin would have to be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this structure:

```
<div class="upload-space">
   <!-- This is the options box -->
   <div class="affix image-options">
       Report
   </div>
```

You can Work with `position:absolute` this way:

```
.upload-space {
  position:relative;
}
.image-options {
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  top:0;
  left:-50px;
}
```

Check this [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vv4q8/)

Answer (score 1):

why using javascript for this?
You can do this with simple CSS.

If I understand your wish you might be looking for something like this?

http://codepen.io/steveHimself1397/pen/gxatc

Steve

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like 
http://tarcisius-ede.nl/
this?

if so see css file for info.
it has a main div (wrapping div) and than the optionbox has negative margin.

we used css media query's to make it fit for different browser widths. 
and that the position of the element is absolute, but that is extra...